# How to generate a multi-line logging output to emphasize for example the begin of a bigger action and the end of it

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

i used to log a title (for example begin of bigger action and the end of it) with a call to my own console utility method: `ConsoleUtil.printTitle("PDF Generation - Start");` with following output:

```
####################################################################################################
#                                PDF Generation  - Start - TimeStamp                               #
####################################################################################################
```

My own method can take several parameters like the decoration character, the width of the title.
The method diplays the title centered.

Is it possible to get the same output with a logging framework like log4j2? Please Step by Step.

It is possible to generate logs with the normal layout and some logs like title with another layout?

I have some background knowledge about log4j and log4j2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All works fine. (except the spaces property)
Is it possible to use a MarkerPatternSelector and delegate the output of the %msg place holder  to an external method call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely it is possible. What I would do for the above is

```
public class MyClass {
    static final Marker TITLE_MARKER = MarkerManager.getMarker("TITLE");
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

    public void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info(TITLE_MARKER, "PDF Generation - Start - Timestamp");
    }    
}
```

then in your log4j2.xml you can configure a MarkerPatternSelector

```
<Properties>
  <Property name="heading">##### as many #s as you want</Property>
  <Property name="spaces">                             </Property>
</Properties>
<Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
  <PatternLayout>
    <MarkerPatternSelector defaultPattern="[%-5level] %msg%n">
      <PatternMatch key="TITLE" pattern="[%-5level] ${heading}%n#${spaces}%msg%n${heading}%n"/>
    </MarkerPatternSelector>
  </PatternLayout>
</Console>
```

The MarkerPatternSelector will using the pattern for TITLE when the TITLE Marker is used in an event. All other events will use the default pattern.

PatternSelectors are plugins so if the ones that come by default with Log4j don't work for you it is always possible to create your own.

Also, Log4j doesn't have a built in way to repeat strings like the #s out of the box. But it wouldn't be difficult to create a RepeatLookup that does that. It would be similar to [UpperLookup](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/UpperLookup.java) but you would use it something like ${repeat:#,30} and then the lookup method would consist of something like:

```
String[] parts = key.split(",");
if (parts.length != 2) {
  return key;
} 
return parts[0].repeat(Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is the right answer. 

Is it possible to center the title like my own method?
(btw the spaces property did not work)
Or maybe it is possible to use an external method for the Layout?

Comment: Yeah, you just have to have it centered in the pattern. Based on your question I have added a repeat pattern converter to be included in Log4j 2.15.0. so to do the spaces you could have your pattern be "%R{#}{60}%n#%R{ } {26}My Text%R{ }{27}#%n%R{#}{60}" for the title pattern. If you think this is the correct answer please upvote it and accept it..